# List of non-filtered values with a filtered value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to put together a reference tool in Power BI where a user can filter data containing property visit information by various clients:

| Client_ID | Property_ID | Date_Start | Date_End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client_1 | 1 | 1/1/2019 | 1/7/2019 |
| client_2 | 1 | 1/5/2019 | 1/12/2019 |
| client_3 | 1 | 1/2/2019 | 1/14/2019 |
| client_1 | 2 | 2/1/2019 | 2/5/2019 |
| client_3 | 2 | 2/2/2019 | 2/8/2019 |
| client_4 | 2 | 2/4/2019 | 2/12/2019 |
| client_2 | 3 | 3/3/2019 | 3/10/2019 |
| client_3 | 3 | 3/9/2019 | 3/13/2019 |
| client_4 | 3 | 3/12/2019 | 3/25/2019 |
| client_1 | 4 | 4/5/2019 | 4/10/2019 |
| client_2 | 4 | 4/6/2019 | 4/9/2019 |
| client_3 | 4 | 4/12/2019 | 4/15/2019 |

1. A user is be able to select one client from a slicer and generate a list of all their property stays (e.g., client_1 property visits):

| Slicer: | client_1 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| Client_ID | Property_ID | Date_Start | Date_End |
| client_1 | 1 | 1/1/2019 | 1/7/2019 |
|  | 2 | 2/1/2019 | 2/5/2019 |
|  | 4 | 4/5/2019 | 4/10/2019 |

2. Here's it he problematic part: User should be able to generate a list of all other clients that stayed at the same properties client_1 stayed at:

| Slicer: | client_1 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
| Property_ID | Client_ID | Date_Start | Date_End |
| 1 | client_1 | 1/1/2019 | 1/7/2019 |
| 1 | client_2 | 1/5/2019 | 1/12/2019 |
| 1 | client_3 | 1/2/2019 | 1/14/2019 |
| 2 | client_1 | 2/1/2019 | 2/5/2019 |
| 2 | client_3 | 2/2/2019 | 2/8/2019 |
| 2 | client_4 | 2/8/2019 | 2/12/2019 |
| 4 | client_1 | 4/5/2019 | 4/10/2019 |
| 4 | client_2 | 4/6/2019 | 4/9/2019 |
| 4 | client_3 | 4/12/2019 | 4/15/2019 |

I am able to generate a list of all relevant properties where client_1 stayed at via the selected "client_1" filter in the slicer, however that filtering also flows down to all other Client_IDs. So in the end I end up just having the same table as in Step 1 above, with all other clients filtered out.  Is there a way to remove the filter context from the "Client_ID" field so only the Property_IDs are filtered to display only the ones were "client_1" stayed?

Real data contains duplicate "Client_ID" values as some clients may have stayed at same property more than once during the period, so that presented an extra challenge when trying to reference all unfiltered values in DAX.

Ultimate goal is to list all clients that stayed at same properties as client_1 during the same time period:

| Slicer: | client_1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client_ID | Property_ID | Date_Start | Date_End | Client_ID | Date_Start | Date_End |
| client_1 | 1 | 1/1/2019 | 1/7/2019 | client_2 | 1/5/2019 | 1/12/2019 |
|  |  |  |  | client_3 | 1/2/2019 | 1/14/2019 |
|  | 2 | 2/1/2019 | 2/5/2019 | client_3 | 2/2/2019 | 2/8/2019 |
|  |  |  |  | client_4 | 2/8/2019 | 2/12/2019 |
|  | 4 | 4/5/2019 | 4/10/2019 | client_2 | 4/6/2019 | 4/9/2019 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would depend on how necessary the active relationship between Clients Table and Visits Table is. These are the assumed tables.

[image]

I'll start with the Inactive relationship:

[image]

Slicer no longer acts on the Visits[Client_ID] column but the visualization continues to collect information about the slicer as opposed to setting the interaction between the slicer and the Table (I used a table viz, sorry) to None via Format / Edit Interactions.

It is not fully tested in different scenarios because the table is small and I gave more time to other options but I suppose that dedicating more time to this option would be the right way to go.

```
Test2 = 
VAR SelectedClient=VALUES(Clients[Client_ID])
VAR CurrentProperty= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]))
VAR FilteredProperties= 
CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]),ALL(Visits),SelectedClient,USERELATIONSHIP(Clients[Client_ID],Visits[Client_ID]))
VAR PropertiesBySC = COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(FilteredProperties,CurrentProperty))
RETURN 
PropertiesBySC
```

[image]

In the following two examples, the relationship between Clients Table and Visits Table remains active.

[image]

As the measure is present in the table there was no need to set a parameter for the "Filters on this visual" related to the measure:

```
Test = 
VAR SelectedClient= VALUES(Clients[ClientName])
VAR CurrentProperty= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]),ALL(Clients))
VAR FilteredProperties= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]),ALL(Visits),SelectedClient)
VAR PropertiesBySC = COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(FilteredProperties,CurrentProperty))
RETURN 
IF(
    ISFILTERED(Clients[Client_ID]) && PropertiesBySC=1 &&HASONEVALUE(Clients[Client_ID]),
    "Property related to " & SelectedClient & "'s visits",
    IF(
        ISFILTERED(Clients[Client_ID]) && PropertiesBySC<>1,
        BLANK(),
        "Multiple clients Selected"
        )
)
```

[image]

Again, it is not fully tested in different scenarios because the table is small and I gave more time to the last option which is not completely tested either.

Ultimate goal, keep the date range for the selected Client (client_1) for each property visited by him/her (1,2,4) and intersect this range with the date range of each row in the Visits table.

```
Test3 = 
VAR SelectedClient= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Clients[Client_ID]))
VAR CurrentProperty= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]),ALL(Clients))
VAR CurrentDateStart=CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Date_Start]),ALL(Clients))
VAR CurrentDateEnd=CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Date_End]),ALL(Clients))
VAR CurrentDateRange=CALCULATETABLE(DATESBETWEEN(Dates[Date],CurrentDateStart,CurrentDateEnd),ALL(Clients))
VAR PropertiesVisitedBySC= CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]),ALL(Visits),Visits[Client_ID] IN SelectedClient)
VAR HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentProperty = //1=Yes|Blank()=No
COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(PropertiesVisitedBySC,CurrentProperty))
////
VAR SCVisitsForCurrentProperty =
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CALCULATETABLE(Visits,ALLEXCEPT(Visits,Visits[Property_ID]),Visits[Client_ID] IN SelectedClient),
    "Date_Start",Visits[Date_Start],"Date_End",Visits[Date_End])
VAR DateRangesForSCVisits= 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATE(SCVisitsForCurrentProperty,DATESBETWEEN(Dates[Date],[Date_Start],[Date_End])),
    "Date",[Date])
VAR HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentPropertyInAnyDateRange=
COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(CurrentDateRange,DateRangesForSCVisits))
RETURN 
//>0=Yes|Blank()=No
IF( 
    HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentProperty=1
    &&
    HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentPropertyInAnyDateRange>0,
    "Property and Dates related to " & SelectedClient & "'s visits"
    )
```

[image]

To avoid problems with multiple selection because the measure is not optimized, I activated the Single Select Option for the slicer.

[image]

Finally, I think it would be easier with a table that allows us to evaluate a DAX Query based on a slicer. Cheers!

**EDIT**

Inactive relationship, visits from the same client on the same property in different date ranges.

[image]

Measure

```
Test2 := 
VAR SelectedClient = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Clients[Client_ID]))
VAR CurrentProperty = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]))
VAR CurrentStartDate = CALCULATE(VALUES(Visits[Date_Start]))
VAR CurrentEndDate = CALCULATE(VALUES(Visits[Date_End]))
VAR CurrentDateRange = DATESBETWEEN(Dates[Date],CurrentStartDate,CurrentEndDate)
VAR PropertiesVisitedBySC = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(Visits[Property_ID]),
    ALL(Visits),
    Visits[Client_ID] IN SelectedClient,
    USERELATIONSHIP(Clients[Client_ID],Visits[Client_ID]))
VAR HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentProperty = //1=Yes|Blank()=No
COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(PropertiesVisitedBySC,CurrentProperty))
VAR SCVisitsForCurrentProperty =
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CALCULATETABLE(Visits,ALLEXCEPT(Visits,Visits[Property_ID]),Visits[Client_ID] IN SelectedClient),
    "Date_Start",Visits[Date_Start],"Date_End",Visits[Date_End])
VAR DateRangesForSCVisits= 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    GENERATE(SCVisitsForCurrentProperty,DATESBETWEEN(Dates[Date],[Date_Start],[Date_End])),
    "Date",[Date])
VAR HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentPropertyInAnyDateRange=
COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(CurrentDateRange,DateRangesForSCVisits))
RETURN 
//>0=Yes|Blank()=No
IF( 
    HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentProperty=1,
    HasTheSCVisitedTheCurrentPropertyInAnyDateRange)
```

Comment: Thank you so much -- this is exceptionally helpful! The first two solutions worked like a charm with my actual data.  Unfortunately though I'm encountering an issue with the 3rd solution involving the date calculations. When applying your approach to both the test data and my actual data, I keep getting an "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected" error message when adding the Test measure to the table. I tried figuring out what could be causing this but alas had no luck yet. Any insight would be tremendously appreciated!

Comment: The example table did not contain duplicate Client_ID visits at the same property. So, I think this was overlooked by me: "Real data contains duplicate "Client_ID" values as some clients may have stayed at same property more than once during the period, so that presented an extra challenge when trying to reference all unfiltered values in DAX".  I only checked the option with the inactive relationship between Clients and Visits. But if you use the same approach guided by the CALCULATETABLE modifiers, I think you would find the solution to the scenario with the active relationship.

Comment: In order to write the measure within a code block, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Yes, DATESBETWEEN(...) in "DatesIntervalBySC_P" VAR (sorry for the weird names) would not work with duplicate clients because the CALCULATETABLE modifiers were returning more than one row for client_1, so VALUES (Visits [Date_Start]) was getting a column with more than one row and DATESBETWEEN() needs a scalar as 2nd and 3rd parameters. This was the reason for the "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected" error

Comment: So what occurred to me was to filter Visits with the same CALCULATETABLE modifiers used previously, this would return repeated rows for client_1 and property=4 but with different date ranges. In the example, it was only two rows.
Only the Date_Start and Date_End columns were selected from that table (1st SELECTCOLUMNS). GENERATE creates a table with a column with all the dates within the different date ranges. Finally, that column was used to compare it with the date range of each row.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks so much for the follow-up and the thoroughly detailed edit! This really helped clear up the error issue and provided a great workaround.  I also liked your Test 3 approach, although I'm still for some reason having difficulty applying your code (copied directly) to the original test data that looks exactly as from your first response (without client duplicates). Just trying to figure out what could be throwing it off on my end, also with a "table of multiple values supplied" error.  Really appreciate all the help and your solutions!

Comment: The old Test3 measure had not been changed because I told you that by using the modifiers of the old Test3 and the last approach to the inactive relationship you could find the solution. In any case, in order not to leave the answer pending, I have completed it. Apologies and good luck.